# combined SELECT query on two tables that have no connection

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to run a combined SELECT query on two tables that have no connection at all?

```
**Table A**         **Table B***
id | A | B | C      id | D | E | F
---------------     ---------------
X1 | 1 | 2 | 3      Y1 | 1 | 2 | 3
---------------     ---------------
X2 | 1 | 2 | 3      Y2 | 1 | 2 | 3
---------------     ---------------
X3 | 1 | 2 | 3      Y3 | 1 | 2 | 3
```

In two queries it would be:

```
   SELECT A,B FROM Table A WHERE id=X2
   SELECT D,E FROM Table B WHERE id=Y1
```

If possible, I'd like to combine those two in something like

```
SELECT (A,B FROM Table A WHERE id=X2) AND (D,E FROM Table B WHERE id=Y1)
```

with only one result set.

Comment: (Select a, b from table1 where id=x2) Union (Select d,e from table2 where id=x1)

Comment: It's only possible if both `SELECT` statements have the same number of columns. I suppose it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION`

```
(SELECT A as col1 ,B as col2 FROM Table A WHERE id=X2) union (SELECT D as col1,E as col2 FROM Table B WHERE id=Y1)
```

Comment: It's only possible if both `SELECT` statements have the same number of columns. I suppose it can't be done.